# Oracle SQL query to retrieve parent records based on a string pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Env: Oracle 12c

I have the following dataset within a table called: `MY_INFO`

```
ID        NAME      INFO   
--------- --------- -----------    
1         Isle 4    L 4 
2         Isle 0    L 5/0   
3         Isle 2    L 6/0/2 
4         Isle 2    L 4/2   
5         Isle 0    L 4/0   
6         Isle 0    L 5/0   
7         Isle 2    L 7/0/2 
8         Isle 3    L 8/3   
9         Isle 2    L 6/0/2 
10        Isle 2    L 4/0/2 
11        Isle 10   L 10    
12        Isle 0    L 11/0  
13        Isle 2    L 11/0/2
```

Given the above records within this `MY_INFO` table and assuming I am using record ID: 10, i.e.:

```
ID        NAME      INFO   
--------- --------- -----------    
10        Isle 2    L 4/0/2
```

Like a hierarchy, I need a means of retrieving all records that following the following pattern, for this record atleast.

In this case though, I need to retrieve just the following three records alone that match, in reverse, i.e.

```
4
4/0
4/0/2
```

So using INFO value: `L 4/0/2`, I now need to branch up to `L 4/0` and retrieve that record and then all the way back to top level record `L 4`

So in the end, the records that I expect to retrieve are:

```
ID        NAME      INFO   
--------- --------- -----------    
1         Isle 4    L 4 
5         Isle 0    L 4/0   
10        Isle 2    L 4/0/2
```

Unsure how to tackle this using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do this...

First i "manually" append a '/' in the block check_string, after which in the block row_gen i generate as many rows as there are the number of '/'. So for a string like L 4/0/2 i wold need 2+1(from check_string) rows to generated.

After that im substringing the main string with a combination of instr function, which will tell me the character position of the 1st , 2nd and 3rd '/'.

And lastly i join with the main table to get the list of records based on the actual values in the table.

```
create table t(id int, name varchar(20), info varchar(50));

insert into t
select 1 ,'Isle 4 ','L 4' from dual union all
select 2 ,'Isle 0 ','L 5/0' from dual union all
select 3 ,'Isle 2 ','L 6/0/2' from dual union all
select 4 ,'Isle 2 ','L 4/2' from dual union all
select 5 ,'Isle 0 ','L 4/0' from dual union all
select 6 ,'Isle 0 ','L 5/0' from dual union all
select 7 ,'Isle 2 ','L 7/0/2' from dual union all
select 8 ,'Isle 3 ','L 8/3' from dual union all
select 9 ,'Isle 2 ','L 6/0/2' from dual union all
select 10,'Isle 2 ','L 4/0/2' from dual union all
select 11,'Isle 10','L 10' from dual union all
select 12,'Isle 0 ','L 11/0' from dual union all
select 13,'Isle 2 ','L 11/0/2' from dual; 

with check_string
  as (select 'L 4/0/2'||'/' as str /*Here you would pass the string that you want*/
        from dual
     )
,row_gen
  as (
select level as lvl
      ,instr(str,'/',1,level) as col1
      ,substr(str
                 ,1
                 ,instr(str,'/',1,level)-1
                 ) as col2
  from dual
  join check_string
    on 1=1
connect by level<=length(str)-length(replace(str,'/')) 
     )
select *
  from row_gen a
  join t b
    on a.col2=b.info

Output
+----+---------+---------+
| ID |  NAME   |  INFO   |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | Isle 4  | L 4     |
|  5 | Isle 0  | L 4/0   |
| 10 | Isle 2  | L 4/0/2 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

dbfiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7d974b5d936c04835e730113d28cd4d6

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LIKE` and `self join` as follows:

```
SELECT T.* FROM
MY_INFO T JOIN MY_INTO T10
ON T10.INFO LIKE T.INFO || '%' -- (OR) ON INSTR(T10.INFO, T.INFO) = 1
WHERE T10.ID = 10;
```